# Struts1.x application not releasing RAM after using it

Tags: java, performance, struts, weblogic12c

i am working on Struts1.x web application and using weblogic server, when performing some processing on very huge data, it consume almost all the RAM but after completing or session timeout, it don't return the consumed RAM.
It never release the RAM until I stop the server or kill forcefully. wanted to know such scenario where the RAM utilization is not released after usage and if it can be solve by tuning weblogic paramter or by some other way.

using the following parameter in weblogic:

```
-Xms12g -Xmx12g -XX:MetaspaceSize=1G  -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1G  
-XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:+UseCompressedOops 
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC 
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled 
-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=68 
-DBASE_CONFIG_LA=/data01/Lending_Analytics_weblogic/LendingAnalyticsPQM/config/ 
-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation 
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2m -Xloggc:/data01/Lending_Analytics_weblogic/LendingAnalyticsPQM/GCLogs/gc.log
```

*** not able to find any GC issue after analyzing the GC logs.

*** fixed all the Memory Leak issue from the code through eclipse memory leak compiler

Comment: Are you saying it *never* releases the RAM, or doesn't release it when *you* think it should release it? It's also impossible to help with the information provided--we have no insight into your code or data, and there's nothing actionable as presented.

Comment: yes. it never release the RAM until I stop the server or kill forcefully. wanted to know such scenario where the RAM utilization is not released after usage and if it can be solve by tuning weblogic paramter or by some other way.

Comment: If it *never* releases it then it's either a memory leak or something still has a reference to it.

Comment: No you can&#39;t force RAM utilization without cleaning. The data might be in use while you think it occupies your RAM.